# How to create a customer hierarchy given a sales invoice line table and a customer table?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

I have what seems like a data modelling problem. I am creating a sales dashboard in Power BI. I have a sales invoice table, and a customer table, as represented below (I have filled in only relevant columns).

```
Sales Invoice Line Table
OrderNo Quantity Price Bill-to-CustomerNo Ship-to-CustomerNo
                       1B                  3S
                       1B                  4S
                       2B                  5S

Customer Table
No  Name
1B   Apple
2B   Beta
3S   Charlie
4S   Delta
5S   Echo
```

I have two categories of customers, 'Bill to customers' and 'Ship to customers'. More than one 'ship to customer' can belong to a 'bill to customer' as seen by Bill to customer number '1B'

I want to create a slicer, where the hierarchy is first Bill to Customer Name, then Ship to Customer Name.

To my understanding, my problem is that the names are in another table. If I'm not mistaken, I could already create this slicer, but with the Customer numbers (by placing 'bill to customer' over 'ship to customer' in the slicer).

My question is, how can I create a slicer, with the above mentioned hierarchy and with customer names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every BillToCustomer "belongs" to a ShipToCustomer, you should have two seperate tables, and you can have filter flow go BillToCustomer -> ShipToCustomer -> SalesInvoice.

```
BillToCustomer(CustomerNo,Name)
ShipToCustomer(CustomerNo,BillToCustomerNo,Name)
SalesInvioce(OrderNo, Quantity, Price, ShipToCustomerNo)
```